# Sqlite select column contains each of ids

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table

```
 CREATE TABLE humans_to_pets (
        human_id   INT  NOT NULL,
        pet_id     INT  NOT NULL
    )
```

where I am storing pairs what human own what pet (many to many).

Given list of pet_id I need to find all humans who owns each pet from the list.

for instance

```
human_id |  pet_id
1           11
2           11
2           12
3           13
4           11
4           12
```

`find([11,12])` should return `[2, 4]`. Only humans 2 and 4 owns both pets 11 and 12.

I am using sqlite 3.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select human_id
from humans_to_pets
where pet_id in (11, 12)
group by human_id
having count(distinct pet_id) = 2
```

Assuming that `(pet_id, human_id)` tuples are unique (which would make sense for this junction table), this can be simplified to not use `distinct`, which would make the query more efficient:

```
select human_id
from humans_to_pets
where pet_id in (11, 12)
group by human_id
having count(*) = 2
```